# Is it possible to reverse CGI binary file?

Tags: binary-analysis, elf, binary

I wanna reverse CGI binary file. 
Is it possible?
What are the recommended tools and guides?
Thank you for reading my question.

```
$ file test.cgi
status.cgi: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux.so.3, for GNU/Linux 2.6.16, stripped
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `radare`. It is a free framework.

`$radare2 -aarm -b32 test.cgi`

More on radare: https://radare.gitbooks.io/radare2book/content/

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you let me know the best linux GUI tools like IDA please?

Comment: hi, you can use `ghidra`

Answer (score 1):

CGI is not a specific type of file; it more so describes the way the file is interacted with. A CGI file could be a script written in any scripting language (e.g. Python, Bash, Perl etc.), or it could be an ELF executable like you have here.

Since it's just a normal ELF, you can use any common disassembly/decompilation tool that you would use for other binaries.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.