# How to reverse engineering ARM architecture ELF file on AMD linux?

Tags: elf

I am reversing an ELF file, it's ARM architecture file. 
But my OS is AMD linux.
How can I do reversing work for the ARM ELF file on AMD linux?

Comment: it doesn't matter, you are reversing statically. use `radare` as a answered in your previous question - https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/27738/is-it-possible-to-reverse-cgi-binary-file

Comment: @R4444, Thank you. for your answers. BTW, I can't find main function with this radare tool, and I can see some html strings, so I think it's a script file. Then what is the best way to reverse this file (compiled script file)?

Comment: can you show us `file filename` output?

Comment: @R4444, you can see it in my previous question https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/27738/is-it-possible-to-reverse-cgi-binary-file

Comment: @R4444, Thank you. I found the main function with cutter tool.

Answer (score 2):

You can do reverse engineering  for almost arm architecture binaries with radare2. 
Radare2 has architecture option -a.

Answer (score 1):

Your host architecture has little to do with reverse engineering, unless you are trying to execute a binary. Decompilers/disassemblers are built to understand a variety of binary formats (not too different from a video player that handles many codecs). As long as your tools support the architecture, you're fine.